# Replacing Pandas Timestamp with datetime module

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working on a function that will convert the timestamp of a dataset (CSV file, loaded with Pandas) from local time to UTC. For this, I would like to use the datetime module since I use it in other functions and scripts that don't necessarily have datasets loaded in with Pandas.

For example, a dataset looks like this:

```
dtg(local)  temperature  wind speed
2017092003     17.3          7.8
2017092004     17.5          12.4
2017092005     17.6          9.2
```

Where dtg is the pandas Dataframe index (yyyymmddHH). The location in question is in UTC+1 and has summer Daylight Saving Time, so the time should be 2 hours lower. I use a function that utilizes the datetime module to correct for this time difference (this part of the function works just fine). This function returns a list of datetime objects (new_index). I wish to assign this list as the Dataframe index, as such:

```
new_index = times_to_utc(df.index_tolist())
df.set_index([new_index], inplace=True)
```

but when I check the data types later, this gives:

```
in[1]: print(new_index[3], type(new_index[3])
out[1]: 2017-09-20 03:00:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>

in[2]: print(df.index[3], type(df.index[3])
out[2]: 2017-09-20 03:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Why do Pandas automatically convert it to a Pandas Timestamp? This is really inconvenient as other functions rely on the input being a datetime object. Can I change the date type for the index to datetime. datetime?

Comment: Try something like this to generate the new Index as a DateTimeIndex? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html or http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html see also https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out via some testing that the pandas timestamp can be compared to a datetime object:

```
in[0]: import pandas as pd
  ...: from datetime import datetime
  ...: df = pd.DataFrame(index=["2017 09 25 12"], columns=["column"])
  ...: df.index = [datetime.strptime(t, "%Y %m %d %H") for t in df.index]
  ...: print(df.index[0], type(df.index[0]))
  ...: print(df.index[0] == datetime(2017, 9, 25, 12))
  ...: print(isinstance(df.index[0], datetime))

out[0]: 2017-09-25 12:00:00 <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
   ...: True
   ...: True
```

meaning that the problem I thought I had was never a problem at all...